# Vapor 3: when returning a model, how to easily also return child objects

Tags: swift, vapor, vapor-fluent

I have a model Campaign, that has multiple Months:

```swift
final class Campaign: Content, SQLiteModel {
  var id: Int?
  var name: String
  var months: Children<Campaign, Month> {
    return children(\.campaignID)
  }
}
```

When I want to return a Campaign in the most basic way, it doesn't include the Months, as computed properties are not Codable as I understand.

```swift
func getOneHandler(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<Campaign> {
  return try req.parameters.next(Campaign.self)
}
```

So, I made a new struct to hold the full object I want to return

```swift
struct FullCampaignData: Content {
  let id: Int
  let name: String
  var months: [Month]?
}
```

And then modified my route handler like this:

```swift
func getOneHandler(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<FullCampaignData> {
  return try req.parameters.next(Campaign.self).flatMap(to: FullCampaignData.self) { campaign in
    return try campaign.months.query(on: req).all().map(to: FullCampaignData.self) { months in
      return try FullCampaignData(id: campaign.requireID(), name: campaign.name, months: months)
    }
  }
}
```

This does work. However, it seems like a lot of work and a lot of boilerplate to do this. What's the normal Swifty "Vapory" way to deal with child objects, or other computed objects in general? Right now it seems to come down to a bunch of different versions of your models (for creation, for returning, the actual full internal one) and then converting between them, but I am hoping there is something I am missing here? Because it's so easy to forget to add a newly added model property also to that special public model.

Or at the very least, if converting between models in indeed the recommended way, is there a way doesn't need all these nested maps/flatmaps in the route handler?

Comment: Manual joins or subqueries is the best way for Fluent 3. Fluent 4 will support eager loading to do this automatically.

Comment: Vapor 4 suddenly sounds very interesting! :) That join/subquery example from imike below really didn't look that much better or easier from what I did myself (see above) :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [SwifQL](https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/) lib for complex queries

I'm not sure that with SQLite it is possible to subquery `Months`, but with `PostgreSQL` it is really easy cause it supports `JSON`

So for PostgreSQL your query may look like

```swift
func getOneHandler(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<FullCampaignData> {
    let monthsSubquery = SwifQL.select(Fn.array_agg(Fn.to_jsonb(Month.table)))
    let query = SwifQL.select(Campaign.table.*, |monthsSubquery| => "months")
        .from(Campaign.table)
        .join(.leftOuter, Month.table, on: \Month.campaignID == \Campaign.id)
        .execute(on: req, as: .psql)
        .all(decoding: FullCampaignData.self)
}
```

or

```swift
func getOneHandler(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<FullCampaignData> {
    let monthsSubquery = SwifQL.select(Fn.array_agg(Fn.to_jsonb(Month.table)))
        .from(Month.table)
        .where(\Month.campaignID == \Campaign.id)
    let query = SwifQL.select(Campaign.table.*, |monthsSubquery| => "months")
        .from(Campaign.table)
        .execute(on: req, as: .psql)
        .all(decoding: FullCampaignData.self)
}
```